# pkg-config error in tensorflow pip install

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm getting the following error when trying to install tensorflow either in virtual environment in pycharm or via the terminal:

```
error: pkg-config probably not installed: FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: 'pkg-config'")
```

But pkg-config is definitely installed on my system.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake - I thought that it required python pkgconfig (which was installed on my system).

sudo apt-get install pkg-config fixed the error.